# DB2- Getting A default table space could not be found with a page size of at least "8192" that authorization ID "***" is authorized to use

Tags: db2

I'm new for db2 and overall databases pls help me.

I'm creating a table within an existing database, but after executing the create statement i got below error msg,

SQL0286N  A default table space could not be found with a page size of at 
least "8192" that authorization ID "DB2ADMIN" is authorized to use.
SQLSTATE=42727

SQL0286N  A default table space could not be found with a page size of at least "8192" that authorization ID "DB2ADMIN" is authorized to use.

Explanation:

The CREATE TABLE, CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE, or DECLARE GLOBAL
TEMPORARY TABLE statement did not specify a table space, and a table
space of the right type (USER TEMPORARY for created temporary table or
declared temporary table) with sufficient page size (at least
""), over which authorization ID "" has USE
privilege, could not be found.

Sufficient page size for a table is determined by either the byte count
of the row or the number of columns.

Hence I created a tablespace

CREATE LARGE TABLESPACE LARGEDATA
     MAXSIZE 512 M

and used this space to create my table, like

create table table_name(***) in LARGEDATA;

I thought 512M should be enough for table with some 15 columns, but I get below exceptions:

SQL0670N  The row length of the table exceeded a limit of "4005" bytes. (Table space "LARGEDATA

Please help...

Thanks in advance for help and time. :)

Answer (score 5):

The row of the table you are creating exceeds the page size of the existent tablespaces.

Probably, you have a database with a default page size of 4KB, and the userspace1 tablespace has the same page size.

When you created the Large tablespace, you are only changing the Row ID size from 1 byte (regular) to 2 bytes (large). However the page size is still the same.

You should create a bufferpool of at least 8KB page size, and then a tablespace that uses that bufferpool.

```
db2 create bufferpool bp8k pagesize 8K
db2 create tablespace data pagesize 8K bufferpool bp8K
```

Comment: Since version 10.5, DB2 has a new option that allows to use a row overflow. This works like in Oracle. For more information: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0061057.html