# "A table space could not be found with a page size of at least "4096" that authorization ID "DB2INST1" is authorized to use." error in DB2

Tags: db2

I'm getting the following error message when trying to create temporary tables in DB2 (11.1) on Ubuntu 16.04:

> SQL Error [42727]: A table space could not be found with a page size of at least "4096" that authorization ID "DB2INST1" is authorized to use.. SQLCODE=-286, SQLSTATE=42727, DRIVER=4.24.92

This is the query I am trying to run (minimal example to demonstrate behaviour):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE testTbl (col1 int NOT null)
```

I have tried creating an 8KB tablespace with an 8KB bufferpool and granting access for the db2inst1 user to it as described in this question: [DB2- Getting A default table space could not be found with a page size of at least "8192" that authorization ID "***" is authorized to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418952/db2-getting-a-default-table-space-could-not-be-found-with-a-page-size-of-at-lea), but this didn't seem to help.

If anyone could give me any insight on why this is happening and how to resolve it would be much appreciated.

Could this be a permissions based issue? The db2inst1 is the default user which was created with the installation so I would assume it has admin privileges over the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CGTT (global temporary table) can only be created in a certain type of tablespace that is different from a regular tablespace.

Use the [syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000929.html) `create user temporary tablespace ...` while running as the db2inst1 user , and ensure it completes successfully before retrying the CGTT.

If db2inst1 is the instance owner as you suggest, then it will have the rights to do this. However, if a different account than db2inst1 wants to run the `create global temporary table` then that account may need to be granted USE access to the user temporary tablespace.

If you plan to use DGTT and CGTT objects then it is wise to ensure at build time per database that relevant user-temporary tablespaces get created for each of the pagesizes 4K, 8K, 16K and 32K pagesize, after ensuring that bufferpools already exist per pagesize, and then ensure that the relevant accounts and roles have USE access, and consider revoking public access to them.

For example, this will create a 4K user temporary tablespace in a Db2-LUW V11.1 database, and will re use the default 4K bufferpool, many of these options can be omitted but this shows what db2look would produce and lets you see what can be changed:

```
CREATE USER TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "UTMP4K" 
         PAGESIZE 4096 MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
         USING STOGROUP "IBMSTOGROUP"
         EXTENTSIZE 4
         PREFETCHSIZE AUTOMATIC
         BUFFERPOOL "IBMDEFAULTBP"
         OVERHEAD INHERIT
         TRANSFERRATE INHERIT
         FILE SYSTEM CACHING
         DROPPED TABLE RECOVERY OFF;
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I didn't realise there was a difference between a permanent and a temporary tablespace. I'm struggling a bit with the syntax for creating a temporary tablespace, could you give me an example please? I am trying the following "CREATE USER TEMPORARY TABLESPACE usr_tbsp MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE;" but it is throwing an error about "MANAGED BY SYSTEM" not being supported in the context it is used.. I'm unsure why it is trying to use managed by system when I am specifying automatic storage. Thanks again

Comment: Answer updated, example works correctly on Db2 V11.1 on ubuntu 16.04