# Create temporary table in db2

Tags: db2

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE  SESSION.TEMP_EMP (EMPNO  CHAR(6));
```

I get error :

A table space could not be found with a page size of at least "4096" that authorization ID "A" is authorized to use.. SQLCODE=-286, SQLSTATE=42727, DRIVER=4.19.56

I use CLP to configure :

```
     db2 connect to sss
     db2 create bufferpool bp8k pagesize 8K
     db2 create tablespace data pagesize 8K bufferpool bp8K
     db2 terminate
```

I create above temporary table again , but still get error. I create temporary table from IBM data studio. The database sss is created by command `create database sss` without any more parameters. Are there any problems if i change tablespace and bufferpool. Because i dont want to change default parameters of database. It harms my database

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["A table space could not be found with a page size of at least "4096" that authorization ID "DB2INST1" is authorized to use." error in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610628/a-table-space-could-not-be-found-with-a-page-size-of-at-least-4096-that-autho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary tables need a user temporary tablespace (not a regular one you created)
Check out this docs about [temporary tables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tables-declaring-temporary)

Here is how you can create a [temporary tablespace](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=spaces-creating-temporary-table)